# Create multiple dataframes by filtering subsets that are not equal to a value in R

Tags: r, function, dataframe, filter, lapply

I have a dataframe with two columns Text and Colours.

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(purrr)

# sample dataframe
df <- data.frame(Text = c("text1", "text2", "text3", "text4"), 
                 Colours = c("blue", "white", "green", "yellow"), stringsAsFactors = F)
```

What I need, is a dataframe, let's say, NOT_Blue that includes all the rows except the rows that includes "blue". In other words a dataframe with all the colours except the ones that are not equal to "blue". In the end I 'd like to write these dataframes like csv files.

For one dataframe using the `dplyr::filter` and `!=` (not equal) would work

```r
not_blue <- df %>% filter(!Colours == "blue")

not_blue
   Text Colours
1 text2   white
2 text3   green
3 text4  yellow
```

The thing is that I need to create a different data frame for each colour/category.

I suppose I'll need to use one of the apply/ map family functions. So I create a vector with the colours hoping to use it in the function.

```r
# colours to feed the function
colours <- c("blue", "white", "green", "yellow")

# trying to make a function

remaining_colours <- function(x) {

  df <- df %>% filter(!Colours == x)
}


# using the formula with map_df of purrr
map_df(colours, remaining_colours) %>% arrange(Text)

# epic fail results
Text Colours
1  text1    blue
2  text1    blue
3  text1    blue
4  text2   white
5  text2   white
6  text2   white
7  text3   green
8  text3   green
9  text3   green
10 text4  yellow
11 text4  yellow
12 text4  yellow
```

Could you please help me or indicate how to make the apply/map/loop for this case?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a way using `lapply`. This creates a list of your desired dataframes.

```
colours <- c("blue", "white", "green", "yellow")

result <- lapply(colours, function(x) {
             df %>% filter(!Colours == x)
          }) %>% 
          setNames(paste0("NOT_", colours))

result

$NOT_blue
   Text Colours
1 text2   white
2 text3   green
3 text4  yellow

$NOT_white
   Text Colours
1 text1    blue
2 text3   green
3 text4  yellow

$NOT_green
   Text Colours
1 text1    blue
2 text2   white
3 text4  yellow

$NOT_yellow
   Text Colours
1 text1    blue
2 text2   white
3 text3   green
```

Comment: thanks alot! how I could export/write the result as a csv file?

Comment: @yiah you can do - `lapply(seq_along(result), function(f) {
  write.csv(result[[f]], file = paste0(names(result)[f], ".csv"), row.names = F)
})`

Answer (score 2):

Inside the function, it was `colours` instead of the `Colours`

```
map_df(colours, ~ df %>% 
                      filter(Colours != .x))

#    Text Colours
#1  text2   white
#2  text3   green
#3  text4  yellow
#4  text1    blue
#5  text3   green
#6  text4  yellow
#7  text1    blue
#8  text2   white
#9  text4  yellow
#10 text1    blue
#11 text2   white
#12 text3   green
```

If we need a `list` of `data.frame`, instead of `map_df`, just use `map`

```
set_names(map(colours, ~ df %>% 
                      filter(Colours != .x)), paste0("df_", colours))
```

Or change the function as

```
remaining_colours <- function(x) {

     df %>% 
         filter(!Colours == x)
  }
```

Comment: thanks a lot! Both solutions are valid. The map_df could more handy in my case since everything goes to one data.frame. In that case I'll need a column with the not matching colour `map_df(colours, ~ df %>% 
         filter(Colours != .x) %>% mutate("NOT matching colour" = .x))`